# Google app engine: Retrieve values from datastore after a particular key value?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm newbie to GAP (Python). I'm using NDB to retrieve all the values from datastore which comes after a particular key value.

Thanks in advance if anybody can help me out with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are setting the key or are using allocate id's otherwise such a requirement would not have a lot of meaning.

You can use the key as an order argument.

e.g. I have a Product model

```
x = models.Product.query().order(models.Product.key)
```

Given this I can then get all keys greater than a specific key with

```
x = models.Product.query(models.Product.key > ndb.Key('Product','001132')).order(models.Product.key)
```

The order is a bit irrelevent but heh ;-)

Comment: Hi Tim! I'm trying to understand the query first." models.Product.key > ndb.Key('Product','001132') " if I do this then I get all the values after the given key value. (Here 001132 is the for Product entity) ????

Comment: In my example , and when you use a key comparison you need to construct a Key for the rhs of the comparison.  So my example (real code) I have explicitly set key name and  I can create a key ndb.Key(Kind, id/name)